# Object property access doesn't work in ES6 function expression

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

I can't access my object property with this ES6 expression :

```
const obj =
{
    name: 'john',
    test: () => console.log('hello'+this.name)
} 
obj.test()
```

I only get "hello", and with this expression it works :

```
const obj =
    {
        name: 'john',
        test: function() {
            console.log('hello'+this.name)
        }
}
```

What's happening here ?

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#sec_traditional-functions-bad-non-methods

Comment: Lots of duplicates: [`[ecmascript-6] arrow function object literal`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Becmascript-6%5D+arrow+function+object+literal)